# Spring 16 - Does custom Visualforce Global Actions not show up in Lightning Experience?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, global-actions, spring16

I am trying out a custom Global Action for Lightning Experience.

I re-read the Release Notes for Spring '16 twice and I think they fixed it to preset 4 actions only (Note/Task/Event/Call) - http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_composer_window.htm?edition=&impact=

But then when I go into Global Publisher Action Layout editor - I see that it says, **Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions** heading and ability to add custom visualforce actions on the layout. But the action does not show up, even if I enable the Visualforce page for Mobile/Salesforce1 in Lightning Experience.

Can someone confirm that this is not open for custom vf based actions? :(

[image]

Comment: Confirmed from my end that it does not support visualforce based global actions .

Comment: That's really too bad, they should relabel the wording on the layout page, as this confuses users to be able to add Actions to Global Layout for Lightning Experience ...